# Thunderbolt bridge connection between mac and pc slow in one direction

Tags: windows-10, mac, thunderbolt-networking

I've connected a MBP 2017 (Big Sur) with an Alienware 17 R5 (Windows 10), both of which support Thunderbolt 3. I'm using a "Thunderbolt Bridge" connection.

The cable is an intel certified CalDigit Thunderbolt 4 cable which is backwards compatible with Thunderbolt 3: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08QL2R7Z3

**Mac connection:**

[image]

**PC connection:**

[image]

I have run connection speed tests on both the mac and the PC using LAN Speed Test. Here is the LAN Speed test results on the mac:[image]

And on the PC:

[image]

The LAN test client on the mac is connecting to LAN Test Server on the PC. On the PC it's doing a file write to a shared folder on the mac. In both speed tests data transfer from the pc to the mac is very slow, but reasonably fast in the other direction.

I've configured a static IP address for each connection.

I've tried:

- Rebooting both machines after the cable has been connected
- Setting net.inet.tcp.tso=0 hinted at here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7090388 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60884019/slow-upload-via-thunderbolt-download-is-fine
- Disabling all firewalls on both Mac and PC
- Making sure PC BIOS and
  drivers are all up-to-date
- Disabled all other network connections on
  both PC and mac
- Set the priority of the Thunderbolt Bridge higher on
  the mac

**Update:** I tried a third PC, an Intel NUC. The thunderbolt connection worked between the Alienware and the NUC, and the Mac and the NUC. For some reason the connection doesn't work between the Alienware and the Mac. Have double-checked for software updates, and everything seems to be up to date.

Comment: How did you get Windows to recognize a TB network adapter? I do not see it on my BootCamp (MBP 2016).

Answer (score 0):

It appears this issue was introduced with Windows 1903 when connecting to some devices. A workaround is to enable "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection":

[image]

After enabling this I then had to re-enable DHCP for my main internet connection. References:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/thunderbolt-networking-is-broken-in-later-versions/3eb526ad-703b-4f04-84e3-a0a24529d921
- https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=185&t=150261

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with Intel MBP 2016 (Win 10 via Boot Camp with Intel's Thunderbolt Networking driver 1.41.1193.0) connected with a certified TB3 cable to M1 MBP 2021 (macOS 12.6.1). It manifested when I transferred large files from M1 to Intel over SMBv3.

Turned out that something in this configuration did not play well with IPv6.

When I connected to the share on M1 by name (both NetBIOS name and Bonjour were affected), it was resolved by Windows into a link-local IPv6 and the transfer speed was pathetic, less than 50 Mbps.

However, when I connected by IPv4 the transfer speed was much better, ~ 2.5 Gbps (a far cry from advertised 20 Gbps, but still).

I "fixed" the issue by disabling IPv6 on the network adapter.